What kind of small to medium town would be present on the border of two opposing nations?
So, a mountain range acts as the only land route between two countries. To the east, a humid land dominated by a massive jungle, which is occupied primarily by orc and orc-adjacent races. To the west is a more mild and flat grassland, with humans as its primary demographic, but a much larger variety of citizen then the east. The town in question lies halfway between, in the mountains that separate the two.
I'm curious not only about what size it might be, but who and what kind of person might live in a mutual border town, what kind of businesses or amenities it might have.

Which real-world parallel do you prefer: Andorra, or Berwick-upon-Tweed?

Need to know more about the politics of the situation to answer. For instance are both sides of the mountain range dominated by single large Empires (i.e. one human, one orc) alternatively is there a human empire on one side and just a lot of warring orc tribes/factions on the other or is it vice versa? Finally are there multiple kingdoms/city states on both sides? The answer to your question most likely depends on the above and in particular on local politics near either end of the pass the town is located in.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

That comment by the automated Community BOT is a bad sign. It means your Q has failed SE's basic metrics for a good question. In this case one problem is there is no objectively right answer to this question. All towns have markets, the need to food and lodging, some degree of administration, the trades... In short, your town can be anything at all. VTC:Opinion-Based. Please take the time to read the [tour] and the following three help center pages to better understand the limits of this site: [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask] and [ask].

On the border of 2 opposing nations? A garrison town, what else. See Sarrebourg, Phalsbourg, Wissembourg, Neuf-Brisach, Belfort,... on the France/Holy Roman Empire border for RL examples. Luxembourg is of th'ilk, to a point: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gibraltar_of_the_North&redirect=no. Have a look at their respective histories and if they're not to your taste, add specific desiderata to your post.

The village of Daeseong-dong comes to mind.

Washington DC comes to mind, historically. Beebe Plain is another, famous for the American house with the stairs that lead up to the Canadian apartments. Europe is full of small border towns, condominiums and houses that belong to one country but are in another country.


Treaty Town
Two powerful leaders on both sides have found a reason to have that town. It could be that neither wants the other to hold the strategic mountain pass, and that they reached this settlement after exhausting battles. Or they wanted a safe passage point for occasional ambassadors going either way.
Expect a small town with a few merchants and their supporting structure (artisans to build and repair things for the merchants, innkeepers, bakers, millers, etc. to feed them, surrounding peasants to grow the food). Despite the treaty protection, there would be a town wall guarded by "the watch" and/or rotating contingents of citizens organized by their guilds. There would be an ostensibly neutral town council and permanent representatives from the two leaders, engaged in obscure, behind-the-scenes power struggles ("Is it permissible to blow an Orkish war horn on a human holy day? What if two movable holidays collide?").
Think of the governing institutions of Andorra.
Refugee Town
The border is disputed, but forceful incursions by one side cause forceful responses by the other. This has led to a tacitly accepted neutral zone along the border, where neither side builds permanent fortifications and no reasonable person builds unfortified towns.
This leaves outcasts, fugitives, high-risk traders in a not-really-governed shantytown. No side dominates the other, and the leading gang lords have a wary respect for each other -- a human killing an orkish trader under the protection of the orkish chieftain either leads to swift and public punishment by the human side, or bloody reprisals by the orks, and you never know which it will be. But the last full-scale civil war was, oh, at least eight months ago ...
Expect small-time traders, bringing in a few mule-loads of food, or cloth, or whatever, and wealthier traders with more bodyguards than clerks or stevedores.


If the city can not grow out into a power on its strength, then the situation is socially unstable.
Neither the humans and absolutely not the orcs are peaceful guys, and only better adapting to jungle or grassland is not a reason to not try to conquer the other side.
The city must become a local power, capable to defend itself from both sides.
Do not think that the humans would be really better as the orcs in this sense. Maybe humans do not eat their mates even if they are hungry, but a little bit of genocide was not ever too far from us, as history shows. No, if humans could do, they would hunt for the orcs in the jungle as for a wild prey. Yes, even for the orc children.
And the orcs... we all know the orcs.
Very likely, neither the orcs and the humans are united. Orcs have many tribes, hating each other often more as the humans. And also many humans would happily ally with orcs to get a revenge on the murders of his people (who have also taken only revenge for something).
The situation is not very chaotic, but surely complex. That orcs ally more often with orcs, and human with humans, has more a cultural as political reason.
The city is a very worthy resource, as it is the only way for a commercial passage. It can get tax on everything, while only they can freely shop on both sides. Things available only on one of the sides - for that, they can ask literally any price on the other side. Remember silkroad from history.
In my opinion, what will happen:

The city will be soon conquered by one of the parties, either by a human or an orc power.
Its neighbors will ally against the city, from both sides, because they can not tolerate such a power threatening them all.
They will overthrow the city and conquer it for themselves.
Go back to 2 many times.

...after a while, once a local power, or and alliance of powers will conquer stable the city. So, they will be able to keep it, does others like it or not. And they start to build an economy, based on the gold (or what the orcs are using for money, for example bear teeth) what they get on the commerce.
That won't be a small city any more.
That will be the capital of an empire.
((Note: it does not matter et all, if humans or orcs will be the rules. Except if the orcs have some inherent disadvantage, like the lack of intelligence. If they don't have, then they are at least equal to the humans))

Las Vegas!
Where else can you go to escape the anti-gambling and prostitution laws of your country? Where can a human go to see an orc cabaret? Where can trade freely move without the taxes and rules of either country?
This would also provide the stability for a city in such a precarious location. The leaders of both countries have needs. And they don't want their party town to go away.

I would postulate a market town. Built for defence and populated by any races providing services for merchants. So inns, prostitutes, travelling gear and a big market. Then guides, guards, traction animals, carts etc,. and other travelling services.
Leaders would be tough & ruthless and collecting taxes in both directions from the merchants. The size would be dependent on the traffic and would probably fluctuate wildly with the seasons. If there's enough traffic it could easily be a city, history has many rich cities that were on trade routes.
